# Where are the ACL permissions being checked when a file is about to be opened in EXT2?

Tags: linux, filesystems, acl, ext2

In the `EXT2 file.c` the open file operation `(.open)` is being pointed to `dquot_file_open` which furthur points to `generic_file_open` which is present in `fs/open.c`.

The `generic_file_open` looks like it just has the below code

```
int generic_file_open(struct inode * inode, struct file * filp)
{
    if (!(filp->f_flags & O_LARGEFILE) && i_size_read(inode) > MAX_NON_LFS)
        return -EOVERFLOW;
    return 0;
}
```

**Where are the ACL permissions being checked when a file is about to be opened?**

When is I googled and went through the code using LXR I found the below path.

**`do_sys_open -> do_filp_open -> path_openat -> do_last -> may_open -> inode_permission -> do_inode_permission -> generic_permission -> acl_permission_check -> check_acl -> posix_acl_permission`**

**but I could not understand how the .open of EXT2 is linked to do_sys_open.**

Any help in letting me know the path to checking the acl permissions during a file open would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at it from the wrong end:  names like `do_sys_open` are system call entry points, and will ultimately go through the VFS layer to find the ext2 `open` routine *after* validating permissions.

Comment: thanks a lot @geeosaur .. I was under the impression that ext2 `open` routine would be called as soon as the open system call is called. your post was of great help .. I understood that initially `do_sys_open` would be called and ext2 `open` will be called after calling a chain of routines from `do_sys_open`

Answer (score 1):

I think you got sidetracked by the ACL code; once the permission has been granted, follow `nameidata_to_filp` to `__dentry_open`:

Within `__dentry_open()`:

```
    f->f_op = fops_get(inode->i_fop);
    /* ... */
    if (!open && f->f_op)
            open = f->f_op->open;
    if (open) {
            error = open(inode, f);
            if (error)
                    goto cleanup_all;
    }
```

This saves the `inode->i_fop->open` function pointer to the autovariable `open`, then proceeds to call it on the `inode` and `f`.

Comment: thanks for the reply @sarnold .. Yeah I was a bit off track since my aim was to find where the permission checking is done .. It was also important for me to note that the function `nameidata_to_filp` is called from `do_last` after the permission checking is done. ext2 `open` is called from `__dentry_open()`. Thanks a lot for the information.